# Getting a "Segmentation fault: 11" when finding number of inversions using mergesort in C++

Tags: c++, mergesort, inversion

I am writing a C++ program that finds the number of inversions in a vector using merge sort. An inversion happens when the `i`'th element is greater than the `j`'th element, where `i < j`. For example, say the vector is `{ 1, 3, 5, 2 }`, then there are 2 inversions: `{3,2}` and `{5,2}`.
The `countNsort` function keeps recursing and dividing the vector until the length of the subvector is only one element. The `countNsortSplit` function performs merge sort to sort and count the number of inversions.

I tried:

1. Different ways of initializing the input vector. `vector<int> a{2,1};`, `vector<int> a; a={2,1};`, and `vector<int> a(2); a={2,1};`.
2. Different ways of splitting the input vector into subvectors. `vector<int> c(a.begin()+half, a.begin()+n);` and `vector<int> c(a.begin()+half, a.end());`, where n is the size of the vector.
3. Different IDEs. Atoms gives me this: `bash: line 1: 13763 Segmentation fault: 11  /tmp/cpp.out [Finished in 20.57s]`, CodeBlocks gives me this: `error: expected expression` for this line: `a={2,1}:`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct returnVal {
    int count;
    vector<int> sorted_array;
};

returnVal countNsortSplit(vector<int> left, vector<int> right, int n) {
    returnVal output;
    int count = 0;
    vector<int> merge;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (left[i] < right[j]) {
            merge[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            merge[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            // increment count by the # of remaining elements in left
            count += left.size()-i;
        }
    }
    output.sorted_array = merge;
    output.count = count;
    return output;
}

returnVal countNsort(vector<int> a, int n) {
    returnVal output;
    if (n == 1) {
        output.sorted_array = a;
        output.count = 0;
        return output;
    } else {
        returnVal left;
        returnVal right;
        returnVal split;
        int half = n / 2;
        vector<int> b(a.begin(), a.begin() + half);
        vector<int> c(a.begin() + half, a.begin() + n);
        left = countNsort(b, half);
        right = countNsort(c, n - half); // need n-n/2 in case of odd length
        split = countNsortSplit(left.sorted_array, right.sorted_array, n);
        output.sorted_array = split.sorted_array;
        output.count = left.count + right.count + split.count;
        return output;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a(2);
    //a = {1,3,5,2};
    //a = {1,3,5,2,4,6};
    a = {2, 1};
    returnVal result;
    result = countNsort(a, a.size());
    cout << result.count << endl;
}
```

Comment: Additional info: An inversion happens when the i'th element is greater than the j'th element, where i<j. For example, say the vector is {1,3,5,2}, then there are 2 inversions: {3,2} and {5,2}.
The countNsort function keeps recursing and dividing the vector until the length of the subvector is only one element. The countNsortSplit function performs merge sort to sort and count the number of inversions.

Comment: You're calling _undefined behavior_ here `merge[k]` you must first resize the vector before you can access it with the indexing operator. Also don't put additional information in comments. You always can [edit] your question.

Comment: Hint: A `std::vector` is zero size when initialized. To add elements: `push_back` or `emplace_back`. For fixed-size: `std::array`.

Comment: Recommend running such programs with asan or valgrind. They sometimes catch the problem much earlier, before the segfault actually manifests. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in you code:

- You do not define the destination vector with the proper size
- You do not test if `i` or `j` have reached to size of the `left` and `right` vectors respectively.
- The initializer for vector `a` in `main()` has an invalid syntax.

Note that you do not need to pass the vector sizes to `countNsort` and `countNsortSplit`.

Here is a corrected version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct returnVal {
    int count;
    vector<int> sorted_array;
};

returnVal countNsortMerge(vector<int> left, vector<int> right) {
    int leftSize = left.size();
    int rightSize = right.size();
    int n = leftSize + rightSize;
    int count = 0;
    vector<int> merge(n);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (i < leftSize && (j == rightSize || left[i] < right[j])) {
            merge[k] = left[i++];
        } else {
            merge[k] = right[j++];
            // increment count by the # of remaining elements in left
            count += leftSize - i;
        }
    }
    returnVal output;
    output.sorted_array = merge;
    output.count = count;
    return output;
}

returnVal countNsort(vector<int> a) {
    int n = a.size();
    if (n <= 1) {
        returnVal output;
        output.sorted_array = a;
        output.count = 0;
        return output;
    } else {
        int half = n / 2;
        vector<int> b(a.begin(), a.begin() + half);
        vector<int> c(a.begin() + half, a.begin() + n);
        returnVal left = countNsort(b);
        returnVal right = countNsort(c);
        returnVal result = countNsortMerge(left.sorted_array, right.sorted_array);
        result.count += left.count + right.count;
        return result;
    }
}

int main() {
    //int values[] = { 1, 3, 5, 2 };
    //int values[] = { 2, 1 };
    int values[] = { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 };
    vector<int> a(values, values + sizeof values / sizeof *values);
    returnVal result = countNsort(a);
    cout << result.count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that it would be more efficient and idiomatic to sort the vector in place and return the inversion count:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

size_t countNsortMerge(std::vector<int>& a, size_t start, size_t middle, size_t end) {
    std::vector<int> temp(a.begin() + start, a.begin() + middle);
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t leftSize = middle - start;
    size_t j = middle;
    size_t count = 0;
    for (size_t k = start; k < end; k++) {
        if (i < leftSize && (j == end || temp[i] < a[j])) {
            a[k] = temp[i++];
        } else {
            a[k] = a[j++];
            // increment count by the # of remaining elements in left
            count += leftSize - i;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

size_t countNsort(std::vector<int>& a, size_t start, size_t end) {
    if (end - start <= 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        size_t middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
        size_t leftCount = countNsort(a, start, middle);
        size_t rightCount = countNsort(a, middle, end);
        return leftCount + rightCount + countNsortMerge(a, start, middle, end);
    }
}

int main() {
    //int values[] = { 1, 3, 5, 2 };
    //int values[] = { 2, 1 };
    int values[] = { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 };
    std::vector<int> a(values, values + sizeof values / sizeof *values);
    size_t result = countNsort(a, 0, a.size());
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```